# Abelian Varieties over C(t) and Galois representations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

I am interested if (part of) Tate's theorem can be extended to Abelian Varieties over 
$\mathbb{C}(t)$. Specifically, let $A$ be an Abelian Variety of dimension $g$ over 
$\mathbb{C}(t)$, and consider the associated Galois representation on torsion
$\rho:G\rightarrow GL_{2g}(\mathbb{Q}_l)$, where $G$ is the absolute galois group of $\mathbb{C}(t)$, and $l$ is a prime number. Since in the isotrivial case - that is, where all fibers are the same Abelian Variety - the representation has finite image, I impose the condition that $A$ is simple and non-isotrivial. Are either of the following true:

(1) The $\mathbb{Q}_l$-algebra generated by $\rho(G)$ is the commutator of the endomorphism
algebra of $A$

(2) $\rho(G)$ acts irreducibly on  $T_l(A)\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}_l}\mathbb{Q}_l$ where $T_l(A)$ denotes the Tate module of $A$.

My (unreliable) guess is that (1) is too much to hope for but (2) has a fighting chance.

Thanks!

Comment: I dont think that (2) holds. Look for instance at the generic fibre of a Shimura curve classifying abelian surfaces with quaternionic multiplication. The action of the quaternions is not scalar but it commutes with Galois and so this would imply that the generic fibre is not simple, which is not true (a Shimura curve is not the projective line, agreed, but it should be possible to manufacture a counterexample from this). The fact that (2) holds over finite fields is quite specific.

Comment: ...on the other hand, I think that (1) holds. Indeed, the Tate conjecture holds over ${\bf C}(t)$ by work of Faltings (see the book on the Mordell conjecture edited by Faltings-Wustholz). The Tate conjecture says precisely that the ${\bf Q}_l$-algebra of endomorphisms of the Tate-module, which commute with Galois, is generated by the endomorphisms of the abelian variety. Now apply the bicommutant theorem (see for instance Lang, Algebra, XVII, Th. 3.2) and the fact that the action of Galois is semisimple (also proven by Faltings) to get (1).

Comment: Thanks, I was unaware that Faltings settled the Tate Conjecture for $C(t)$. As for my (2), I just stated it poorly I realize, I should have asked for the action on rational homology,without going to the Tate module. I'm perplexed by your comment about finite fields though: Isn't (2) just as false there as stated? Take an Elliptic curve over a finite field whose endomorphism field splits over $l$. Doesn't that make the action reducible?

Comment: You are right abut the fact that it is even wrong over finite fields, sorry. What is specific about finite fields is that you can read the presence of two distinct simple factors from the fact that the char. pol. of the Frobenius has two distinct factors over $\bf Q$. 

Comment: One more correction: Faltings proves the Tate conjecture over fields finitely generated over their prime fields so that does not include ${\bf C}(t)$ (but ${\bf Q}(t)$ for instance). It is not clear to me whether this implies (1) and (2) over ${\bf C}$.

Comment: Aha, thanks for clarifying. It turns out the answer to (1) is no, and I would guess its no for (2 as well. Faltings gives a counterexample in his paper "arakelovs theorem for abelian varieties". see my answer here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/116900/for-which-fields-does-the-isogeny-theorem-hold/122157#122157.