# Infinitely many curves with isogenous Jacobians

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, abelian-varieties, jacobians, isogenies

Let $g\geq 4$. Are there infinitely many compact genus $g$ Riemann surfaces with (mutually) isogenous Jacobians?

Does the situation change in positive characteristic?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by isogeny? Are you asking for a holomorphic maps between the tori? Or surjective group homomorphisms with finite kernel (in which case you are looking at finite-index subgroups of a lattice).

Comment: Being principal, jacobians do not embed as finite-index sublattices of other jacobians (i.e. are not finitely-covered by any other jacobian).

Comment: I thought those two notions of isogeny were equivalent over the complex numbers.

Don't elliptic curves provide a counterexample to your second comment?

I wanted to prove that given a hyperbolic complete curve $X$, there are only finitely many hyperbolic curves it maps to. By looking at Jacobians, we are led to the above question (with the guess that the answer is no!)

Comment: @RK I think Martel's second comment is wrong, too. I don't know the answer to the question you asked, but if you want to see a proof of the statement in your comment, this is de Franchis's theorem.

Comment: You are right (and i had forgotten) that the two notions of isogeny are the same (after a translation along the jacobian) -- see the first section of Milne's notes on abelian varieties. Now i'm concerned with what type of isogenies we are interested in, i.e. do we expect them to preserve the polarization, to preserve up to a multiple $d$, or not. If we don't care about polarizations, then we're just talking about self-coverings of tori (of which there are many). If we demand that the polarization be preserved, then we're talking about the (finite) automorphism group of a ppav. 

Comment: a related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/116900/for-which-fields-does-the-isogeny-theorem-hold

Comment: Err, just to clarify; I meant holomorphic/etale; I'm okay with the polarizations not matching up.

@FelipeVoloch Any ideas where to find references for stuff like this? I'm having some trouble tracking anything down.

Comment: I know this question is 3 years old, but this paper might be of your interest: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.2545.pdf

Comment: The conjecture 2.1 of this paper  https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.03552 implies that, for $g \leq 9$, every ordinary abelian variety over a finite field is isogenous to infinitely many Jacobians.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you excluding $g = 2$ and $g = 3$?

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn I just don't expect it to be true because $\mathcal{M}_g$ and $\mathcal{A}_{g,1}$ are birational for $g=2,3$.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn: ig g = 2,3 it's very easy to produce examples with explicit AGM constructions (see Richelotr or Humbert for g=2, Donagi & Livne or L & Ritzenthaler for g=3)

Answer (score 4):

I believe I have an example in genus 5:

Humbert curves (see either Varley's "*Weddle's Surfaces, Humbert's Curves, and a Certain 4-Dimensional Abelian Variety*", or exercise batch F in chapter 6 of ACGH) are in 1-1 correspondence with 5-tuples lines in the plane -- the plane being $I_C(2)$ -- up to projective transformations of the plane. These 5 lines are the image of the double cover from $W^1_4(C)$ to rank < 4 quadrics enveloping the canonical image of $C$. Each of the 5 lines is marked with 4 points - its intersection points with the other four lines, and is the 2-quotient (under the map $W^1_4\to I_C(2)$ ) of an elliptic curve which lies inside the Jacobian of $C$, where four points are the ramification points. The Jacobian of C is isogenous to the product of these five elliptic curves.

Giving the plane the projective coordinates $x,y,z$, we now consider the lines: $$x=0,\quad y=0,\quad x=z,\quad y=z,\quad x+y=az.$$
The $y$ (resp $x$) coordinate of the intersection points on the first (resp second) line are $0,1,a,\infty$; whereas the $x$ (resp $y$) coordinate of the intersection points on the third (resp fourth) lines are $0,1, 1-a, \infty$. Since $x\mapsto 1-x$ takes $0\to1,1\to0,\infty\to\infty, a\to1-a$, the four elliptic curves associated with these four lines are isomorphic. Finally, The elliptic curve associated with fifth line has an extra involution, (flipping $x,y$), so it is the same curve regardless of $a$. Hence if we pick any $a_1,a_2$ which give isogenous elliptic curves, we get isogenous Humbert curves.

Answer (score 2):

(Edit: this doesn't answer the question - I misread it to mean that we were looking for infinitely many isogenies of distinct Jacobians in arbitrary genus.)

There are explicit constructions that provide infinitely many examples of pairs of non-isomorphic curves with isogenous Jacobians in any genus.

Jean-François Mestre has a Richelot-like construction that, for each $g \ge 2$, produces a $g+1$-dimensional family of pairs of hyperelliptic curves with $(2,\ldots,2)$-isogenous Jacobians.  For the details, see https://www.ams.org/journals/jag/2013-22-03/S1056-3911-2012-00589-X/ (if you don't have access to that, then there's an earlier version in French at https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.3470 , and a translation of that version into English at http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~smith/Mestre---pairs.pdf ).

In characteristic $p$, you can produce examples over finite fields almost trivially using Frobenius.  Let $q$ be a power of $p$.  For each curve $C$ over $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$, there is a Galois-conjugate curve $C'$ over $\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ defined by raising the coefficients of the defining equations of $C$ to the $q$-th power, and then $q$-th powering defines a degree-$q$ morphism $\pi: C \to C'$, which (in genus $g>0$) induces an inseparable isogeny between $J_C$ and $J_{C'}$.  If $C$ and $C'$ are not isomorphic (and in general they are not), then you have a pair of distinct isogenous Jacobians.

Comment: Note that this does not answer the question, which is whether there exist infinitely many non-isomorphic curves with Jacobians isogeneous to a fixed abelian variety.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.  I've added a comment to indicate this.

Comment: Your last example works for the intended question over infinite fields of characteristic $p$, instead of finite ones, because you can take the pullback of any curve corresponding to a point in the moduli space with transcendental coordinates by infinitely many different powers of Frobenius, and the Jacobians will be isogenous.

Comment: @WillSawin: by "infinite" you mean "not algebraic over $\mathbf F_p$".

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn That would be accurate although I guess I didn't say "over all infinite fields of characteristic $p$" so maybe I am safe.