# Mordell-Weil group of an abelian variety on the perfect closure of a finitely generated field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, abelian-varieties

This question is closely related the question [Over which fields does the Mordell-Weil theorem hold?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108543/over-which-fields-does-the-mordell-weil-theorem-hold)

I consider the following question:

> (1) Let $K$ be a finitely generated field extension of $\mathbb F_p$, $K^\text{per}$ its perfect closure, and $A$ be an abelian variety over $K$. Is $A(K^{\text per})$ finitely generated?

I know that the answer is yes if $A$ is a non-isotrivial elliptic curve (this is Theorem 3.3 of  [this 2010 paper by Ghioca](https://www-cambridge-org.resources.library.brandeis.edu/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/274435C0F11F14DFD5F2DD2C0231F8DE/S0008439500015381a.pdf/elliptic_curves_over_the_perfect_closure_of_a_function_field.pdf)). But because of this very article (and because there is also a 2017 [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.07142.pdf) by Rössler proving a somewhat similar statement for an abelian variety satisfying some conditions), I am pretty sure that there is no proof of a positive answer in full generality to my question (1) at this time.

So my real questions are: is the answer to question (1) conjectured to be "Yes"? If so, is there a reference which states this conjecture? Or is it a "folklore conjecture"? Or on the contrary, is there a known counter-example?

Comment: If I understand correctly, can't you always reduce the problem to a minimal field over which the Abelian variety is not isotrivial? And if this field happens to be a finite field, then the group contains $A(\overline{\mathbb F_p})$ which is not finitely generated. On the other hand, if the Abelian variety is not isotrivial over the function field of a curve, we can extend it a neron model over the curve and then the Mordell Weil group would just be the set of sections of the Neron Model. Any map from a curve to an Abelian variety would factor through the Jacobian of the curve (ctd...)

Comment: (ctd...) and therefore the set of sections would be a subgroup of group of homomorphisms which is essentially described by the endomorphism of the Jacobian which is finite generated. So shouldn't it be true in general that over a curve, any non isotrivial Abelian variety has finitely generated Mordell Weil group?

Comment: In my previous comment, you don't need to consider the Neron model, you can simply say that any map from $Spec K^{per}$ to the abelian variety extends to a map from the curve to the Abelian variety and proceed from there. I don't know what happens in higher transcendence degree.

Comment: Let me just add that if question (1) had a positive answer, then the torsion in $A(K^{\text{per}})$ would be finite. This has been proved recently by Ambrosi and D'Addezio (https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.08423, Theorem 1.2.2).